# Young's inequality for convolution

Tags: fourier-analysis, convolution

In Grafakos' Classical Fourier Analysis (third edition) on p. 40 the following example of an application of the Riesz-Thorin interpolation theorem can be found:

[Young's inequality convolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TEns.png)

The bound of $T: L^1 \rightarrow L^r$ is clear by Minkowskis integral inequality. However, I do not see, why $T:L^{r'} \rightarrow L^\infty$ is bounded by $\|g\|_{L^r}\|f\|_{L^{r'}}$. Since $r'$ is the conjugate exponent of $r$, $1\leqslant r \leqslant \infty$, Hölder's inequality may be used, but I do not see how. Grafakos defines the convolution on locally compact groups $G$ with left invariant Haar measure denoted by $\lambda$ such that $(G,\lambda)$ is $\sigma$-finite by

$\displaystyle (f \ast g)(x) := \int_G f(y)g(y^{-1}x)d\lambda(y)$

I think the best would be to show that $\vert f \ast g \vert$ is bounded.

Comment: I can't figure out what the problem is. Yes, the plan is to show that $|f*g||$ is bounded. In fact Holder says exactly that it's bounded by $||g||_r||f||_{r'}$. Ok, Holder plus translation invariance of the measure. What do _you_ get when you apply Holder to that integral?

Comment: I would proove it like that: $\vert f \ast g\vert(x) \leqslant \int_G \vert f(y)g(y^{-1}x) d\lambda(y) = \|fg\|_{L^1} \leqslant \|f\|_{L^{r'}}\|g\|_{L^r}$. I think that I do not understand the third equality, because $\|fg\|_{L^1} = \int_G f(y)g(y)d\lambda(y)$.

Comment: In fact the second integral is _not_ $||fg||_1$; why do you say it is? What's true is $\int|f(y)g(y^{-1}x)|dy=||fh||_1$, where $h(y)=g(y^{-1}x)$.

Comment: Aaaaahhh...you're right. That was my problem. Thanks. Somehow I was confused.

Comment: This can be also seen from the fact that $T$ is (essentially) self-adjoint. Then that $T^\ast = T : L^{r'} \to L^\infty$ is bounded follows immediately from $(L^r)^\ast = L^{r'}$ and $(L^1)^\ast = L^\infty$.

Comment: That is very nice. However I do not think that it works on a general locally compact group since it is not endowed with a structure like the concept of an inner product. Is this right?